# How do I show that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \le \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

The following lemma and proof is from Real Analysis with Real Applications by Davidson and Donsig:

> Lemma 6.3.2. If $R$ is a refinement of $P$, then
>   \begin{align*}
> L(f,P) \le L(f,R) \le U(f,R) \le U(f,P)
> \end{align*}
>
> Let $f(x)$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$. The following are equivalent:
>
> $(1)$ f is Riemann integrable.
>
> $(2)$ For each $\epsilon >0$, there is a partition $P$ so that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$
>
> Proof $(1) \implies (2)$: If $f$ is Riemann integrable, let $L=L(f)=U(f)$. Let $\epsilon >0$. We can find two partitions $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ so that $U(f,P_{1}) < L + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $L(f,P_{2}) > L-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let $P$ be their common refinement, $P_{1} \cup P_{2}$. By Lemma 6.3.2., 
>   \begin{align*}
> L-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}<L(f,P)\le U(f,P) < L + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   and so $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \le \epsilon$, proving $(2)$.

How do I show that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \le \epsilon$?

Comment: Because $L-\frac\epsilon2<L(f,P)$, we may subtract $L(f,P)$ from both sides of the inequality $U(f,P)<L+\frac\epsilon2$ to obtain the desired inequality.

Comment: Visualize on the number line. If two numbers $a, b$ lie between two given numbers $c, d$ then distance between $a, b$ can't exceed the distance between $c, d$. This means $$c\leq a\leq b\leq d\implies b-a\leq d-c$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: That's a very helpful way of thinking about it

Comment: Typical arguments about inequalities used in various proofs in real analysis are damn obvious if one visualizes in terms of distance on number line. Unfortunately the focus in high school is on the algebraic manipulation and not geometric intuition.